# Parity operator and tensor products

Tags: tensor-products, exterior-algebra, supergeometry, supermanifolds

When we consider usual vector spaces like $\mathbb{C}^n$, it is simple to consider tensor product operations, like $\mathbb{C}^n\otimes \mathbb{C}^m \cong \mathbb{C}^{n\cdot m}$, or $\mathbb{C}^n\wedge\mathbb{C}^n \cong \mathbb{C}^{{n \choose 2}}$. What happens when we have superspaces? That is, what is $ \mathbb{C}^{n|m}\otimes \mathbb{C}^{p|q} $ and $ \mathbb{C}^{n|m}\wedge \mathbb{C}^{n|m} $? where $ \mathbb{C}^{n|m} = \mathbb{C}^{n}\oplus\Pi\mathbb{C}^{m}$ where $\Pi$ is change of parity operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tensor product distributes over direct sum and parity is additive with respect to tensor product: so

$$\text{even} \otimes \text{even} = \text{even}, \text{even} \otimes \text{odd} = \text{odd}, \text{odd} \otimes \text{odd} = \text{even}.$$

This gives

$$\mathbb{C}^{n \mid m} \otimes \mathbb{C}^{p \mid q} \cong \mathbb{C}^{(np + mq) \mid mp + nq}.$$

For exterior powers the situation is more complicated, because it turns out that taking exterior powers of an odd vector space corresponds to taking *symmetric* powers. It's easier to describe what happens here in a coordinate-free way. If $V, W$ are (even) vector spaces and $\Pi W$ denotes change of parity (so that $\Pi W$ is odd) then taking exterior algebras converts direct sums into (graded) tensor products, which gives

$$\Lambda^{\bullet}(V \oplus \Pi W) \cong \Lambda^{\bullet}(V) \otimes \Lambda^{\bullet}(\Pi W)$$

where $\Lambda^{\bullet}(\Pi W)$ is actually isomorphic as an algebra to the *symmetric* algebra $S^{\bullet}(W)$, with the elements of $W$ having odd parity. Taking the degree $k$ part of both sides (with respect to the exterior product grading) gives

$$\Lambda^k(V \oplus \Pi W) \cong \bigoplus_{i+j=k} \Lambda^i(V) \otimes \Lambda^j(\Pi W)$$

where $\Lambda^j(\Pi W) \cong S^j(W)$ with the elements of $W$ having odd parity. So the even part of this is the sum over $j$ even and the odd part of this is the sum over $j$ odd.